# Filter by date range in ASPxPivotGrid

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I am using an ASPxPivotGrid to display order data in an aspx website. When I put a column in the "filter area" that has a date value, it displays a checked list of dates to choose from (see below). Is there a setting or workaround to get it to show a date-range or calendar popup to filter by?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ASPxPivotGrid provides the [Prefilter](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument7313) object which can be used to filter the grid contents by complex criterion.